# No wifi menu and "No Wi-Fi adapter found" but can use netplan to connect to wifi [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager, lenovo

So I don't have an option for wifi in the menu:

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX4NH.png)

And in the wifi tab of settings it says "No Wi-Fi adapter found":

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA56F.png)

But I can still connect to Wireless Networks by editing my "/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml" file then executing `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` like so:

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR4E9.png)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad s340. Let me know if any extra information is needed, Thank You!

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

**For a Desktop installation** (Server installation is different) **of Ubuntu...**

Confirm that `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Change your `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` to the following, keeping the indentation, spacing, and no tabs, exactly as you see it...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then go to the NetworkManager applet on the right side of the top panel, select `Wi-Fi Settings/Select Network`, and create your wireless network connection profile.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you've described is a direct and entirely expected result of asking netplan and *not* Network Manager to manage your wireless. When you click the menu at the top; that is, the Network Manager applet, NM shows you nothing because you've told NM that it is no longer in charge. It is saying, "Sorry, that's no longer my job."

If you expect NM to manage your wireless, entirely revert all your changes to netplan and reboot.